# SharePoint Online - Wiki Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

Just looking for some advise. We use SharePoint Online in our organisation and just wondering what other organisations use for managing organisation policies ? Do you use Wiki libraries or Document Libraries ? What’s your preferred choice and experiences ?

Answer (score 0):

A document library is a repository in SharePoint that allows documents to be managed and versioned. Document libraries have many other benefits such as customizable views, ability to filter and sort, addition of new columns / metadata, ability to trigger workflows and the ability to customize in many other ways. They are an ideal for storing policies.

Reference:

https://collab365.community/how-to-manage-policy-and-procedure-documents-in-sharepoint/